# Error: "Undefined reference to operator<<(std::ostream&, Dogs const&)"

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

On C++, I am trying to make a Linked List which would append a whole class.
However, I am always getting the same error:

```
Undefined reference to operator<<std::ostream&, Dogs const&)
```

I have 3 files, 2 headers and 1 CPP.

This is how the headers look like:

**LinkedList.h:**

```
// A class template for holding a linked list.
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H
#define LINKEDLIST_H
#include <iostream>     // For cout and NULL
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
   // Declare a structure for the list
   struct ListNode
   {
      T value;                // The value in this node
      struct ListNode *next;  // To point to the next node
   }; 

   ListNode *head;   // List head pointer

public:
   // Constructor
   LinkedList()
      { head = NULL; }

   // Destructor
   ~LinkedList() {};

   // Linked list operations
   void appendNode(T);
   void displayList() const;
};


//**************************************************
// appendNode appends a node containing the value  *
// pased into newValue, to the end of the list.    *
//**************************************************

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::appendNode(T newValue)
{
   ListNode *newNode;  // To point to a new node
   ListNode *nodePtr;  // To move through the list

   // Allocate a new node and store newValue there.
   newNode = new ListNode;
   newNode->value = newValue;
   newNode->next = NULL;

   // If there are no nodes in the list
   // make newNode the first node.
   if (!head)
      head = newNode;
   else  // Otherwise, insert newNode at end.
   {
      // Initialize nodePtr to head of list.
      nodePtr = head;

      // Find the last node in the list.
      while (nodePtr->next)
         nodePtr = nodePtr->next;

      // Insert newNode as the last node.
      nodePtr->next = newNode;
   }
}

//**************************************************
// displayList shows the value                     *
// stored in each node of the linked list          *
// pointed to by head.                             *
//**************************************************

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::displayList() const
{
   ListNode *nodePtr;  // To move through the list

   // Position nodePtr at the head of the list.
   nodePtr = head;

   // While nodePtr points to a node, traverse
   // the list.
   while (nodePtr)
   {
      // Display the value in this node.
      cout << nodePtr->value << endl;

      // Move to the next node.
      nodePtr = nodePtr->next;
   }
}
#endif
```

**Dogs.h:**

```
#ifndef Dogs_H
#define Dogs_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Dogs;
template <class T>

ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Dogs&);
istream& operator >> (istream&, Dogs&);

class Dogs
{
private:
    string dgName;
    string dgBreed;
    string dgColour;
    string dgDad;
    string dgMom;


public:
    Dogs(string name ="", string breed ="", string colour ="", string dad ="", string mom ="")
    {
        dgName = name;
        dgBreed = breed;
        dgColour = colour;
        dgDad = dad;
        dgMom = mom;
    }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Dogs&);
    friend istream& operator >> (istream&, Dogs&);


};

#endif
```

I would really appreciate if you could point me out where my problem is.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your header says that `ostream& operator<<(sstream&, const Dog&)` exists, but you have not shown any code that defines that operator. Why do you think it exists?

Comment: As I have understood, I did not define an operator. I still have a vague knowledge about operators. Could you send me a link about operators? It would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: An operator is just a funky name for a function. Write the function that inserts a `Dog` object into an object of type `std::ostream`.

Comment: This is what I have attempted: `Dogs operator+(const Dogs& a) {
  Dogs dog;
  dog.dgName = this->dgName + a.dgName;
  dog.dgBreed = this->dgBreed + a.dgBreed;
  dog.dgColour = this->dgColour + a.dgColour;
  dog.dgDad = this->dgDad + a.dgDad;
  dog.dgMom = this->dgMom + a.dgMom;
  return dog;
 }` 
Am I doing it right?

Comment: You've defined `operator+`; that's not `operator<<`. I haven't read the code, and I don't intend to. If you want to know about implementing `operator+` for `Dog` objects (which seems pretty weird), ask a new question.

Comment: Then why are you replying to this question? If you're trying to help me, do it right.

Comment: Your **question** is about **why** the compiler complained that `operator<<` wasn't found, and that's what I responded to. If you want to ask about how to implement some other function, that's a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the line with the template specification

```
template <class T>
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Dogs&);
```

and do not forget to define the operator.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. However, could you be more precise about defining the operator? Thank you!

Comment: @Imad In the header there is only a declaration of the operator. You have to define it that is you need to write code how this operator will output an object of the class Dogs.

Comment: I have made an attempt on defining an operator in **Dogs.h**, however, it still shows the same error. Here is what I have written `Dogs operator+(const Dogs& a) {
  Dogs dog;
  dog.dgName = this->dgName + a.dgName;
  dog.dgBreed = this->dgBreed + a.dgBreed;
  dog.dgColour = this->dgColour + a.dgColour;
  dog.dgDad = this->dgDad + a.dgDad;
  dog.dgMom = this->dgMom + a.dgMom;
  return dog;
 }`

Comment: @Imad In your question there is being said about another operator. I answered the question. So this code that you are showing in the comment has nothing common with the question. If you have a question about how to overload operator + you can ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I realized my attempt was completely different from my problem. I have solved it now.

Comment: @Imad I'm glad to hear that.